# Multifile uplaod- all files checkout to the uploader automatically, how to resolve this?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, check-out

Uploaded pdfs to Sharepoint and all the pdfs became checkout out to me? How to check them in so that anyone can make changes?

Comment: I figured it out. If you have uploaded a folder containing multiple files, usually they will get checked-out to you by default for security. What you can do is group the files by "uloaded by" . All files get selected in a group. Then click on the 3 dots for any file and check-in and all files will get checked out and anyone can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether set "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" as Yes. Please change it to No.

Comment: Thanks Emily and where can I check this? I am a non-administrative user.

Comment: Go to Library settings -> Versioning Settings -> Require Check Out.